# Removing a class, then adding it back results in a different display

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a certain css styled class called "line". On a button click (PLAY button) I remove this class from my element "song_info" then add a new class called "standard". On another button click (PAUSE button) I remove the class "standard" then re-add the class "line".

```js
function play_button() {
  document.getElementById('song_info').classList.remove("line");
  document.getElementById('song_info').classList.add("standard");
}

function pause_button() {
  document.getElementById('song_info').classList.remove("standard");
  document.getElementById('song_info').classList.add("line");
}


window.onload = function() {
  document.getElementById("play_button").onclick = play_button;
  document.getElementById("pause_button").onclick = pause_button;
}
```

```css
.css3gradient {
  width: 298px;
  height: 180px;
}

body {
  margin: 10px;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

#play_button {
  top: 65%;
  left: 113px;
  position: absolute;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

#pause_button {
  top: 65%;
  left: 191px;
  position: absolute;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

#songContainer {
  width: 198px;
  height: 50px;
  position: absolute;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  top: 50px;
  left: 60px;
  z-index: -2;
}

#albumContainer {
  width: 198px;
  height: 50px;
  position: absolute;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 0;
  top: 72px;
  left: 60px;
  /*z-index: -1;*/
}

#songWrapper {
  position: absolute;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: auto;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: -2;
}

#albumWrapper {
  position: absolute;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: auto;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  /*z-index: -1;*/
}

#songWrapper span.line {
  position: absolute;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  /*margin: 15px;*/
  width: auto;
  top: 35%;
  left: 50%;
  animation: marquee 10s linear infinite;
  z-index: -2;
}

#albumWrapper span.line {
  position: absolute;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  width: auto;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  animation: marquee 10s linear infinite;
  z-index: -1;
}

#songWrapper span.standard {
  margin: 15px;
  visibility: visible;
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  width: 149px;
  height: 45px;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  z-index: -1;
  /*
  margin-top: 11px;
  width: 200px;
  visibility: visible;
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px;
  left 20px;
  */
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

#albumWrapper span.standard {
  margin: 15px;
  visibility: visible;
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  width: 149px;
  height: 45px;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  z-index: -1;
  /*
  margin-top: 11px;
  width: 200px;
  visibility: visible;
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px;
  left 20px;
  */
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

@keyframes marquee {
  0% {
    left: -17%;
  }
  100% {
    left: -50.4%;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="css3gradient">
  <div class="idiv">
    <div id="songContainer" class="marqueeContainer">
      <div id="songWrapper" class="loaded">
        <span id="song_info" class="line shadowedObj">No Song Is Currently Playing!!!&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;No Song Is Currently Playing!!!&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;No Song Is Currently Playing!!!</span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="albumContainer" class="marqueeContainer">
      <div id="albumWrapper" class="loaded">
        <span id="album_info" class="line shadowedObj">Album is longer and long enough&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Album is longer and long enough&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Album is longer and long enough</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="idiv">
    <button class="button" id="play_button">PLAY</button>
    <button class="button" id="pause_button">PAUSE</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

The expected behavior is that the css styling would return to normal. However this is not the case and the position is raised rather significantly. Wouldn't we always expect the styling to be the same when a given class is removed and then re-added? What exactly is going on that it has different styling? What can be done to achieve the intended effect and revert css changes via adding and removing a class?

An example can be found here: [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/14gax7w6/1/)

Comment: Note that Stack Snippets wrap the HTML you provide in a `body` element, so I've removed your `head` and `body` elements in the snippet (since `body` had a class on it, I replaced it with a `div`). I checked to be sure this didn't stop the snippet replicating the problem (just being paranoid); it still does, as expected. Also, I recommend not including the fiddle link. The snippet is sufficient, and having a fiddle link encourages people to answer with a fiddle instead of correctly putting the full content of the answer here on-site.

Comment: I might be dumb and not understand this correctly but for me absolutely nothing changes when pressing the play and pause button. I guess this might be browser specific?

Comment: Fantastic stuff making sure the question has all the relevant HTML and CSS! And that CSS behavior is just bizarre...

Comment: @NewEyes - I'm guesing you're using Firefox? I'm using Brave (Chrome-like) and definitely see the behavior. I **don't** see it in Firefox. I wish I still had Legacy Edge installed... (I do see the behavior in Chromium-based Edge.)

Comment: I'm on Microsoft Edge. Shame on me , I know

Comment: @NewEyes - Legacy or Chromium-based? (Basically, v44-, or v79+?)

Comment: @NewEyes - I just uninstalled Chromium-based Edge so I could access Legacy. I don't see the behavior there. Common denominator: Blink (Chromium's rendering engine).

Comment: Version 44.17763.831.0 I think thats still legacy

Comment: I guess you want to remove the marquee animation and return to static text. In that case, you just need to add "animation: none" rule in your class rule. Additionally, you are having additional margin and other styles in your .standard rule.

It is better to have all the common styles in base rule and then add the animation on play state.

Comment: @Awais - Tags don't go in question titles, and removing the invalid `//` in the CSS is a substantive change it's not appropriate to make.

Comment: There are many workarounds to fix this, but the actual reason for the problem is unknown and interesting

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I am currently working on that mistakenly commit edit, but its overridden by yours. :(

Comment: @Awais - I don't think the question needs further editing.

Comment: @Anakin - If you come up with one, would you add it to the community wiki answer below?

Comment: @SparkleStep - Just FWIW, `//` does not start a comment in CSS. CSS only supports `/*...*/` style comments. By putting `//` in front of a style declaration, you make the CSS invalid. What modern browsers seem to do with that is treat just the one declaration you did it on as invalid, but you can't count on that. Use `/*..*/` instead. This **isn't** the problem above, I checked by fixing all of them, but figured I'd mention it. (I also updated the snippet, since otherwise it's a bit of a red herring.)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder There is a typo Error of comment //margin:15px

Comment: @Awais - Yes, but you have to be **very** careful fixing typos like that, in case they are the problem. In this case, they weren't and see above, I fixed all the places the OP did that since it didn't change the behavior and was a red herring. When in **any** doubt, don't change the OP's code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you've found a bug in [Blink](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blink_(browser_engine)) that it inherited from WebCore in [WebKit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebKit) (Blink started as a fork of WebCore). It's probably worth reporting it to the WebKit project and perhaps also to the Chromium project that Blink is part of.

I base this assessment on:

- The same classes really should result in the same display.
- The problem happens on browsers like Brave, Chrome, Chromium-based Edge, and Safari (WebKit), and does not happen on Firefox (which uses Gecko) or Legacy Edge (which uses EdgeHTML)

Here's a workaround created by [Anakin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4379934/anakin), see comments in the code:

```js
function play_button() {
  document.getElementById('song_info').classList.remove("line");
  document.getElementById('song_info').classList.add("standard");
}

function pause_button() {
  document.getElementById('song_info').classList.remove("standard");
  document.getElementById('song_info').classList.add("line");
}


window.onload = function() {
  document.getElementById("play_button").onclick = play_button;
  document.getElementById("pause_button").onclick = pause_button;
}
```

```css
.css3gradient {
  width: 298px;
  height: 180px;
}

body {
  margin: 10px;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

#play_button {
  top: 65%;
  left: 113px;
  position: absolute;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

#pause_button {
  top: 65%;
  left: 191px;
  position: absolute;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

#albumContainer {
  width: 198px;
  height: 50px;
  position: absolute;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 0;
  top: 72px;
  left: 60px;
  //z-index: -1;
}

#songWrapper {
  position: absolute;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: auto;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: -2;
}

#albumWrapper {
  position: absolute;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: auto;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

#albumWrapper span.line {
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  width: auto;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  animation: marquee 10s linear infinite;
  z-index: -1;
}

#albumWrapper span.standard {
  margin: 15px;
  visibility: visible;
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  width: 149px;
  height: 45px;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  z-index: -1;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

@keyframes marquee {
  0% {
    left: -17%;
  }
  100% {
    left: -50.4%;
  }
}

#songWrapper span.line {
  /* removed top and right property */
  position: relative;
  width: auto;
  overflow: hidden;
  animation: marquee 10s linear infinite;
  z-index: -2;
}

#songWrapper span.standard {
  /* there is no need to change into a block element
     so, what's really important in this class is removing the animation */
  animation: none;
}

#songContainer {
  /* now we move this element down to make it near with #albumContainer */
  position: absolute;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 198px;
  height: 30px;
  /* decrease the height */
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  top: 72px;
  /* move this down a little more */
  left: 60px;
  z-index: -2;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="css3gradient">
  <div class="idiv">
    <div id="songContainer" class="marqueeContainer">
      <div id="songWrapper" class="loaded">
        <span id="song_info" class="line shadowedObj">No Song Is Currently Playing!!!&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;No Song Is Currently Playing!!!&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;No Song Is Currently Playing!!!</span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="albumContainer" class="marqueeContainer">
      <div id="albumWrapper" class="loaded">
        <span id="album_info" class="line shadowedObj">Album is longer and long enough&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Album is longer and long enough&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Album is longer and long enough</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="idiv">
    <button class="button" id="play_button">PLAY</button>
    <button class="button" id="pause_button">PAUSE</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

That uses a `div class="css3gradient"` as its outermost element (because the Snippet itself provides `body`), but it works just fine when you're using `body class="css3gradient"` as the outermost instead.

Comment: One of the workarounds, explaination inside the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/qoLa0w48/

Comment: @Anakin - Nice one! Added.

Comment: For anyone else coming across this, bug report is located [here.](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1070822)